# Multiple Excel SEARCH function criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I want to be able to return the position number of the text in a cell as you do with SEARCH function but is this possible with multiple criteria?

e.g. Text in cell is "Iphone 7 Sep 18 $20"

=SEARCH("Sep",F10,1)
I am looking for "Sep" and SEARCH has returned position 10 - ok

But what if that cell could be any of the 12 months? I want the position number returned if the cell has any of the 12 months. Is this possible using SEARCH or some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Msearch(llist As Variant, s As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long, sTemp As String

    If TypeName(llist) = "Range" Then
        sTemp = llist.Value
    Else
        sTemp = llist
    End If

    If InStr(sTemp, ",") = 0 Then
        Msearch = InStr(s, llist)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Msearch = 0

    arr = Split(sTemp, ",")
    For Each a In arr
        i = InStr(s, a)
        If i > 0 Then
            Msearch = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

It can be used like `SEARCH()`, except the first argument can be a comma-separated list:

[image]